# Apex tests using Finalizers causes Metadata API deploy to result in LIMIT_EXCEEDED?

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, mdapideploy, transaction-finalizers

We've used Copado to deploy changes between environments for a couple years, but for the past couple weeks, we've seen our deployments in Salesforce complete successfully (in the Deployment Status UI with the two circles), and then automatically retry again, until we get:

> Fatal Error LIMIT_EXCEEDED: Try deploying again. Your deployment
> exceeded its maximum retry limit. If you keep seeing this error,
> please contact Salesforce Customer Support.

It happens for very simple deployments (just a field): what causes Salesforce to retry it?

For some of these deployments, we see the changes in the Setup Audit History, for each retry (so duplicate lines in that history), despite a deployment that ends with Failed.

For example, when watching the deployment in Workbench (via Metadata API Process Status), we see that this one succeeded at 2021-03-09T03:06:20
[image: DeployResult 1]

But then there's another one, same id and Created Date, but that started seven seconds later:
[image]

And finally this one, same id and Created Date, but that started 9 seconds after the second one:
[image]

And a few seconds after that, the Status changes to failed, but there are no componentFailures, only successes. Why is it failing without any failures?
[image]

Copado says it's a Salesforce issue, and Salesforce says it's a developer issue.

The closest open known issue I can find is [Deployment Fails with UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: admin operation already in progress" or "LIMIT_EXCEEDED error" When there is more one Deployment in queue.](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001JnfoQAC), but we don't have more than one deployment in queue (according to the Deployment Status UI). Is there another way of checking to see if there are pending deployments that aren't showing up in the UI?

Any other ideas? We're running all tests which takes 45 minutes, but that doesn't seem excessively long compared to other instances I've heard about.

Our DeployRequest records (all of these succeeded, with the exception of the one that was cancelled) don't all seem to overlap, though some were created close in time:
[image]

UPDATE:
This started when we deployed code based on the Kevin Poorman's [apex Promise implementation](https://github.com/codefriar/promiseV3) (which is really nice to use and appreciated!).

I reproduced it in a fresh developer org using class [one](https://gist.github.com/pyao-bwc/8d14826f2d449a8fa1fb8c46207834e7), [two](https://gist.github.com/pyao-bwc/68cb39e83deffdf37d19327da6da5827), [three](https://gist.github.com/pyao-bwc/eb84886a302cf165a299fe0d96827a8e), and [four](https://gist.github.com/pyao-bwc/95e5f7919be382226ad29793b39a294b). When trying to deploy a field label change via workbench running all local tests, I can reproduce the LIMIT_EXCEEDED result:[image]

Comment: what are you deploying exactly (i see 43 components) and how are you deploying? I'm not clear on if you replicated this behavior purely using workbench  (with no copado involvement) or not.

Comment: Ah, thanks for looking Kris. This deployment includes 25 custom apex classes, 1 trigger, 4 custom fields, a duplicate rule, 2 flows, three layouts, a profile password policy, a permission set, FLS for three profiles, and 2 validation rules. But this same behavior also happens on the simplest deployment. We're deploying through Copado, and I'm just just using Workbench to try to get more information about deployment status (since we don't get that through the UI or Copado).

Comment: How does the deployment get triggered? Manually initiated, from a source control push, etc. The "simplest" answer sounds like copado sending multiple request at once and running into the issue but I would've suspected they could've helped with that

Comment: Yes, Copado triggers it (and we use it on schedule). If it's sending multiple requests at once, would we see multiple deployments in the Deployment Status UI (in a list of Deployments waiting - I forget the text exactly). Is there any way of querying for deployments awaiting execution? The thing that's surprising to me is that the same deployment id is being retried multiple times.

Comment: Is what you're trying to deploy, deployed in the end of all this? You can query `DeployRequest` with the tooling api (see [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/210692/how-to-query-deployment-details-in-deployment-status-is-it-even-possible)) to see if you see multiple rows. I also see this [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000351065&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1) about how sending multiple requests at once/close together present this error message. I'd assume the answer lies in your Copado setup and making sure multiple things aren't triggered/scheduled at once.

Comment: Thanks, Kris! Yes, what we're deploying is deployed in the end, it just takes closer to 4 hours rather than 45 minutes. And yes, using the tooling API to query DeployRequest was what I was looking for! I posted a screenshot above with our results (the deployments close to each other are Copado deployments with multiple steps). I'll keep an eye on it next time we do a simple deployment to see how things look.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem in a fresh DE org with four classes! I updated the original post with those four classes that I used, and happy to give anyone the username/password for the developer org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another customer posted the same problem in the Apex Transaction Finalizers community:
https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/0D54S00000ANXvQ

Sounds like a bug - both of us have open cases with Salesforce.

Comment: Did you have any outcome from the support case?