# is there an API to get current/finished deployments?

Tags: api, deployment, status

I checked Salesforce APIs and only found a method for `deploymentStatus(Id deploymentId)`.

Does someone know how to do similar functionality to the `Deployment Status` page, where you can see past deployments and get `Id` of ongoing deployment?

Also looked today through Postman collection for APIs, but no luck (

P.S. maybe I missed something in SOAP apis though

Comment: Thanks @PhilHawthorn I'll check, if it returns correct information. For some reason nor Google, nor autosearch showed this question

Comment: thanks @PhilHawthorn it seems to be the answer. Can we somehow merge the questions and make https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/341633/16508 as accepted answer?

Comment: @PhilHawthorn one thing that I don't like is that original question is not resolved even though it has correct answer